# Retrieving objects from Parse using Swift 1.2

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm new to networking, Xcode, and Parse, and I was just following a YouTube tutorial but for some reason the code won't run. Here it is.

```
func CallData(){
    var query : PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "QuestionsAndAnswers")
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("DZfARcuav8"){

        (ObjectHolder : PFObject!, error : NSError!) -> Void in
        if (error == nil){
            self.Question = ObjectHolder["Question"] as! String
            self.Answers = ObjectHolder["Answers"] as! Array
            self.Answer = ObjectHoler["Answer"] as! String
            if (self.Answers.count > 0 ){
                self.QuestionLabel.text = self.Question
                self.Button1.setTitle(self.Answers[0], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                self.Button1.setTitle(self.Answers[1], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                self.Button1.setTitle(self.Answers[2], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                self.Button1.setTitle(self.Answers[3], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            }
        }
        else{
            NSlog("There is something wrong")
        }
    }
}
```

The error message says

> Cannot invoke 'getObjectInBackgroundWithId' with an argument of type '(String, (PFObject!,NSError!) -> Void)

Comment: Well, what does the Parse documentation say this method looks like?

Comment: He's using Swift 1.2. Parse docs are for 1.1

Comment: Well, then what does Swift try to autocomplete it into?

Answer (score 0):

You must remove the PFObject! and NSError! ! mark the closure didn't return an optional type. try the follwing code

```
 func CallData(){
    var query : PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "QuestionsAndAnswers")
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("DZfARcuav8"){

        (ObjectHolder, error) -> Void in
        if (error == nil){
let object = ObjectHolder as [NSObject: AnyObject]
            self.Question = object["Question"] as String
            self.Answers = object["Answers"] as Array
            self.Answer = object["Answer"] as String
            if (self.Answers.count > 0 ){
                self.QuestionLabel.text = self.Question
                self.Button1.setTitle(self.Answers[0], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                self.Button1.setTitle(self.Answers[1], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                self.Button1.setTitle(self.Answers[2], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                self.Button1.setTitle(self.Answers[3], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            }
        }
        else{
            NSlog("There is something wrong")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After doing that the errors from the getObject line go away, but like 6 more errors show up around where I set the variables. Thanks for helping.

Comment: you must remove the ! symbol. just see the updated answer. and kindly mark the answer as solved. to help others people find the true answer

Comment: Yeah my code is identical to yours, but I still have three errors on the three lines after the first if statement. It's saying that it can't assign the values, or that the object can't be converted to an array

Comment: Okay I changed the as! Array to as! [String] and now the all say they cannot assign the value

Comment: see the updated answer. you must downcast ObjectHolder to a dictionary object

Comment: Yeah it's still not working because the NSDictionary isn't part of the PFObject library

Comment: Kindly take a screenshot of the error and send me the link

Comment: kindly switch [PFObject: Anyobject] to [NSObject: AnyObject]

Comment: Sorry I was just testing something, but when I do that I get the exact same error

Comment: Just thinking, may not work, but shouldn't the holder be of type PFObject? I maybe wrong but might be worth a try

Comment: Can you take a screenshot again

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure if this can assist you.. it did helped me though in my coding..

```
func CallData(){
var query : PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "QuestionsAndAnswers")
query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("DZfARcuav8"){
    (ObjectHolder, error) -> Void in
    if (error == nil){

        ObjectHolder!.setValue(self.Question, forKey: "Question")
        ObjectHolder!.setValue(self.Answers, forKey: "Answers")
        ObjectHolder!.setValue(self.Answer, forKey: "Answer")
```

....

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
var query = PFQuery(className: "score")
query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("j5xBfJ9YXu", block: {
    (obj, error)in
    if let score = obj! as? PFObject {
        println(score.objectForKey("name"))
    } else {
        println(error)
    }
})
```